# DropDown List Logics in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode8

I have made two DropDown List one with the `country name` and second with the `cities name`.If i select country USA it should show me the cities of USA in second DropDown list and when i select UK it should show list of UK cities. Can anyone help me?? I'm quite new.

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code.

Answer (score 0):

In view did load getList of country from server. And in text field delegate method get city list on behalf of selected country id or name.

```
 - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
         if (textField == self.countryTextField)
         {
            // pass your countryListArray here in picker view
         }
         else if (textField == self.cityTextField)
        {
           // get city for selected country here.
           // Call web service for city names.
        }
}
```

Comment: my drop downs are not in picker view they r in table view under a button . when click button the table view shows the list. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: ok take these element in an array and and reload the table view.

Comment: show and hide table view according to your requirement.

Comment: Thats what I'm asking how to do it . @Vinay Kumar

Comment: @omer ios has provided picker view from this. Why are you wasting your time to create much complex logic.

Comment: as per client requirement man i have to do so. Can u help me in this case? @Vinay Kumar

Comment: @omer explain properly what you wants to do?

Comment: You have two different table view for country and city or have only one.

Comment: but1 having table1 list of country and but2 having table2 list of cities . when click but1 show country and when click but2 show list of cities. Now i want that if i click but1 and select USA from list it should show list of cities of USA  when we click  but 2 and same for UK related cities. @Vinay kumar

Comment: you can do this with table view didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: first display name of country on the selection of county get city name for selected country. For identifying type of table view use tableview tag from identity inspector.

Comment: @NAVEEN KUMAR can u help me?

Comment: @omer I think you have 2 textFields and need to show two different tableViews which the second tableView should change data according to first one's selection, right?